# How do I set up tsconfig.json files in multi-project environment with shared code?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

My folder structure is as such:

```
root
|-- app1
    |-- node_modules
    |-- tsconfig.json
    |-- ts
|-- app2
    |-- node_modules
    |-- tsconfig.json
    |-- ts
|-- shared
    |-- ts
    |-- typings
        |-- missing-definitions.d.ts
    |-- tsconfig.json
```

Both `app1` and `app2` are separate apps with separate dependencies and builds, but they both access a few files with `shared` by doing something like `include SharedFile from '../../shared/ts/SharedFile';`. They also include `missing-definitions.d.ts` which defines a few modules that didn't have `@types`. `shared` contains shared code, but is not a buildable app by itself.

When building the apps, `tsc` works great and gives no errors/warnings. vscode also seems to work fine within `app1` and `app2` files. I run into issues when I open shared files in vscode. vscode can't seem to find definitions for the modules defined in `missing-definitions.d.ts` or for modules that exist entirely within the other app's `@types` despite the `shared/tsconfig.json` file pointing at those directories.

**My question is** -- how do I set up `tsconfig.json` in each of the folders to make vscode work? I'm a bit confused about whether I should be using `baseUrl`, `paths`, `typeRoots`, and/or `include` in each of the configs.

Here's what I have for `app1/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*" : [
                "node_modules/*",
                "node_modules/@types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./ts/**/*.ts",
        "../shared/typings/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

No matter what I set for the `shared/tsconfig.json`, it seems that vscode doesn't read/parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `npm` and [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) for this, which I automate with [symlink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/symlink) to handle my nested dependencies. You don't have to actually *use* `npm`, besides using it to manage your [*local* dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths).

If you are OK with this approach (and at least a bit familiar with `npm`), you can:

1. Create a [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file for each project (right next to the respective `tsconfig.json` files)
2. Add `shared` as a [local dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) to the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) under `app1` and `app2`, for example:

```auto
"name": "app1",
"dependencies": {
    "shared": "File:../shared"
}
```

3. Sync with symlink, executed from the `root` folder:

```auto
symlink ./ --execute
```

4. Set `moduleResolution` to `"node"` in your respective `tsconfig.json` files

This will automatically and near-instantly synchronize `shared` to `app1` and `app2`. If that's not required, then neither is `npm link` or symlink, and you can just run `npm install` in your two app folders.

> Note: If you omit `--execute` from symlink, you can see the list of commands without them being executed.

Comment: My `shared` folder isn't a complete project/module by itself. It's basically just a loose collection of .ts and .d.ts files. Looks like your solution is pretty clever for importing shared code into a project, but my main issue is that vscode doesn't know where to find definitions for the shared code itself. Does your solution handle that, or are all of your shared parts stand-alone modules?